# How to use WP oembed script outside the_content

Tags: wordpress, video, custom-post-type

I've a custom post type "video" and wanted to show videos like youtube, dailymotion in a specified area using WP default oembed script.
So i'm using a custom field"video url", but the problem is that **oembed** work in **the_content** not with custom field. so how can i do this. or any other solution

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If the custom field only contains the video URL like `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ`, then you can get the oEmbed HTML code with [wp_oembed_get](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_oembed_get):

```
$videourl = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ';
$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get($videourl);
echo $htmlcode;
```

If your custom field contains more than just the URL, you could use the `the_content` filter to do the same thing the `the_content`-function does:

```
$content = "<h2>this video is great</h2>\n<p>check it out</p>\n"
  . "[embed]http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ[/embed]";

$htmlcode = apply_filters('the_content', $content);
echo $htmlcode;
```

Comment: Thanks that really work, but it works on direct url not when i use get_post_meta example $videourl = 'using post meta code here';
$htmlcode = wp_oembed_get($videourl);
echo $htmlcode;

Comment: Thanks that works i figure out on second one. and how to change the width and height of embed video

Answer (score -2):

Here is a complete answer to your question. It is also a cleaner and quicker method, using `wp_oembed_get`, rather than shortcode. Of course, change `video_url` to the name of your custom field.

This code checks that the `video_url` field is not empty, then oEmbeds the video.

```
<?php if (!((get('video_url', TRUE))=='')) {
    echo wp_oembed_get( get('video_url', true) );
}?>
```

Comment: You have to change `video_url` to the name of your custom field, otherwise you will get `Call to undefined function get()`. I have this exact code active on 10+ websites, so I know it works... It is not an untested suggestion.

Comment: The answer is not complete without the implementation of the custom field. It is still not cleaner nor quicker than the other one.